# Find a name in a list if the name is spelt wrong

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I've got a list of names which some code checks against to see if the person exists, and if so do some stuff..

My issue is that I want to handle the case of the name being entered incorrectly.. I.e.  I have a list of names

```
Bob
Frank
Tom
Tim
John
```

If I type in Joohn, I want it to ask me if I meant John. If I type Tm, I get asked if I meant Tim, if I say no, it asks if i meant Tom..  Etc..

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name doesn't appear in the list, you can use algorithms like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to determine which entries in the list are closest and suggest those

Answer (score 1):

The first thing would be to look in the list to see if you have an exact match. If not you calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the word entered by the user and every element in the list. You suggest the one that has the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to be limited to a list of people and want to search for common names you can use Google API service to submit spell check requests and receive in return a suggested spell correction for the query:

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/03/10/check-your-spelling-with-google/